# How to display textbox depending upon elements in ViewBag containing a list

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

This is my controller code:

```
const string template = "clm_adj_process_cd ('@[CdCode]',varchar) ~f.src_dm_platform_cd ('@[EM]'==,varchar) ~paid_date_skey('@[22/09/12]',date)";

        string[] arr = template.Split('~');
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        List<string> list2 = new List<string>();

        foreach (string a in arr)
        {
            string[] sub1 = a.Split('(');
            list.Add(sub1[0]);
            string[] sub2=sub1[1].Split(',');
            string[] sub3 = sub2[1].Split(')');
            list2.Add(sub3[0]);


        }



        ViewBag.Label = list;
        ViewBag.DataType = list2;
        return View();
```

This my code in the view:

```
<div>
 @foreach (var label in ViewBag.Label)
 {
      @label

    <br /><br />   
 }

 </div>
```

this is displaying the first list.

Alongside each element of the first list i neet to put a textbox or date picker etc
depending on elements in list2

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast it into `List<string>`

```
  <div>
 @foreach (var label in (List<string>)ViewBag.Label)
 {
      @label

    <br /><br />   
 }

 </div>
```